# How do I set my entire row to zero if an element in my row is also zero?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
a = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2)

[[[1 0]
  [1 1]]

 [[1  1]
  [1 0]]]
```

I want to set any row in this matrix that has a 0 to 0 using numpy. So in this case, 
it would look like this,

```
[[[0 0]
  [1 1]]

 [[1  1]
  [0 0]]]
```

can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare against `0` and look for `ANY` match along the last axis `axis=-1` ( or third axis `axis=2` in this specific `3D` case) and then use this `mask` to assign zeros -

```
a[(a==0).any(axis=-1)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: a
Out[16]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 0]]])

In [17]: a[(a==0).any(-1)] = 0

In [18]: a
Out[18]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's an alternative version (using the zero value):

```
>>> a
array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
>>> a.all(axis=-1,keepdims=True)*a
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [0, 0]]])
```